# fork() failed (1: Operation not permitted)

Tags: ios, permissions, fork

I'm new to ios.
I'm facing a problem about permission. fork() failed (1: Operation not permitted)

I want to build an open source library implemented in c for ios.
Can "fork()" function be used on ios??
If It could, how can I solve that problem??

Answer (score 3):

No. Every iOS application is a separate process. You can create new threads, not a new process.

Also see [Porting an application with fork() to pthread_create()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503083/porting-an-application-with-fork-to-pthread-create)

Answer (score 1):

fork() can only be used on jailbroken phones.