# How to guarantee a process starts at an exact time in iOS

Tags: ios, c, core-audio

We are playing a metronome audio file at time intervals (bpm), while simultaneously recording an audio file.  However currently the start time of the two threads are not exactly simultaneously, and there is a slight time difference, which for music, is not allowable.

What strategies can we use to guarantee that the two processes start at the exact same time (or under a few milliseconds)?

Thanks!

Comment: Under iOS you can't start new processes (unless it's in a jailbroken environment).

Comment: @EricPostpischil You cannot `fork` a process in iOS. You can, however, create new threads. The OP is conflating `process` and `thread` here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088155/fork-failed-1-operation-not-permitted

Comment: @EricPostpischil Really? iOS allows you to use `fork`? I don't think so.

Comment: @rmaddy: Ah, yes, well, iOS does allow me to use `fork`, but not you. Sorry about that. However, the OP has created two threads and merely wants to synchronize them. So it is apparent that “process” is used in the English sense, not the operating system sense. The OP is asking how to synchronize two things, not how to create a new process.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes thank you, we are using two.

Comment: Have you considered adding the two audio signals to produce one signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most accurate and reliable way of achieving this is to implement audio record and metronome playback in CoreAudio audio render/input handlers rather than using higher level APIs and relying on synchronising two threads.  None of the mechanisms in @David H's answer provide any guarantees about thread execution by the kernel, although they'll probably all work most of the time on a lightly loaded system.

The callbacks are called on a real-time thread managed to CoreAudio, and synchronously with the hardware audio-clock  - which is probably asynchronous with the kernel's timers.

You will need to load the metronome sample into memory and convert to the output format on initialisation - probably using one of the AudioToolbox APIs.  The audio render callback simply copies this to the output buffer at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of three ways to get this done (but obviously I never tested them).

Each of your threads should do all the initialization they can up front, then wait for an "event". A few timing events I can think of:

- use a Notification - both threads an listen for some "start" notification. That should be fairly quick.
- have both threads do keyValue listening - so they both are listening for changes to some property on a known object, like appDelegate (or a singleton), or any object they both know (delegate?)
- have each call a delegate when there initialization is done. When both are "ready", the delegate can send each a message, one after the other (on the main thread) to "start".

You could also experiment with NSLock and friends - not sure what kind of latency you would get there. Key-Value Observing is pretty fast and lightweight, and works on any thread.

Comment: Thanks, will look further into this.