# Separate sandbox for ios cocoa touch static library

Tags: ios, security, cocoa-touch, static-libraries, sandbox

I wanna create a static library that will do some security sensitive operations. It is important for me that the other applications that use my static library can not access data of the static library.

Actually it is important that both data that I save in the disk and also in memory at run-time can not be accessed via host app. So my questions is that how can I provide a separate sandbox for the static library so that host app can not access these information.

There are some security sensitive libraries that I know have `.a` files and I am wondering how they provide the security for their application. Here is a link to `paypal` iOS SDK:

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK

**Update**

According below developer link, we can use sand-boxing key at entitlement file to enable sand-boxing. 
It says that iOS app are sandboxed by default.
But what about iOS static libraries? Whether they are sand-boxed too? If no, how we can sandbox it?

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AboutEntitlements.html

**Update**

In Android OS when you are developing a project library you can define a tag in the `manifest` of this project to force Android OS to run the library codes into separate process (By the way the host process can not access the runtime memory of the library process). So I think we should have an equivalent option for this behavior on the iOS too.

**Update**

Please notice that we want to protect the data agains the host app even at runtime. One of the big problems regards to accessing the data of UI elements via reflection. suppose someone are entering its cards data in Paypal SDK and the host can access the entered data via reflection. Then the developers of host app can access all card information and its authentication data and use them for their usages.

Comment: Would the iOS Security Enclave be of any use?  [article](https://blog.trailofbits.com/2016/06/28/start-using-the-secure-enclave-crypto-api/), [guide](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf)

Comment: I do not understand your comment, may you please specify more?

Comment: The iOS Security Enclave can generate a secure key pair for you, the private part of which can never leave the Security Enclave, but as I think through this, it's not clear that would help in your situation.  You _could_ wrap your library in a separate app, which would of course be sandboxed, and use a [custom URL scheme](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1) for communication between your app and the library app.

Comment: Note that there are restrictions on [background execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW1), and you might have to pretend to do one of the allowable background activities.

Comment: @JoshSanford I do not want to do any background operations, I just want to find a way that when user press an button in host app and open the viewcontroller of my library then the host app can not access data that my library save on runtime. One way is to tell OS to run my libraries data in a separate OS process(separated that app main process).

Comment: I haven't found an authoritative source for this, but my understanding is that iOS does not allow separate processes except as separate apps.  It does allow multiple threads, but that won't help you with sandboxing.  That's why I mentioned background execution.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15897505, http://stackoverflow.com/q/12088155, http://stackoverflow.com/q/6503083.

Answer (score 1):

Libraries and frameworks belong to the hosting app. Especially the code of a static lib is included in the binary of the app, and there is no separation. You cannot create a separate sandbox for a lib, too.

Your static lib may protect its data by encrypt its files on disk with a symmetric key. But an attacker may extract the key from your lib and may decrypt the data.

Comment: So how paypal and other financial companies that share  .a file to third developers provide the required security?

Comment: I don't know. I think they use proven methods (e.g. TSL/HTTPS) for communication with their servers, and put private data into the keychain. I know that they have not an own sandbox. Linking a static library is like adding .o files to the app. (Note: You create static libraries with a tool called `ar`(1), short form for _archive_).

Comment: Please notice that we want to protect the data agains the host app. If we save the data in the keychain, the host app also can access it -of course the main problem is not here, because we can encrypt them via a secure key from server. The main problem is when the host can access what user enter in the third library UI. suppose someone are entering its cards data in Paypal SDK and the host can access the entered data via reflection.

Comment: I understand your use case, but you cannot protect the data against the host app, because there is no separation between host app and library.